# how to spy and drag scroll bars of browser application in blueprism?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am not able to spy scroll bars of browser application in blueprism using any of those 4 spying methods. After spying, how to drag it to the required position ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

What method are you attempting to spy the element you need on the webpage?  Depending on the spying method, BP may not need to visibly see the element to interact with it.

If you're using surface automation or AA, you could always try sending the Page Up/Page Down keystrokes to navigate the web page.  That could be combined with a loop where you send the keystroke and then add a wait for the element you're interacting with.  If it is still not visible you would re-enter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement scrolling is by sending "Send keys" like page down, page up, down arrow. You have to build a logic that will do the send key once and verify the right element.